# Can't use Selenium send_keys() to WYSWYG editor

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to automate posting articles to my blog which is serviced by Naver with Selenium.

The problem is I can't put text to the editor.
I have tried to use `send_keys()`, but it does not work.
Here is my Python Selenium code that I have tried.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')    

driver.get('https://section.blog.naver.com')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class = 'login_button']").click()
time.sleep(1)

driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByName('id')[0].value=\'" + user_id + "\'")
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByName('pw')[0].value=\'" + password + "\'")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@title = 'Sign in']").click()
time.sleep(1)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@bg-nclick = 'hmp*s.write']").click()
time.sleep(1)

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
driver.switch_to.frame('mainFrame')

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/article/div/header/button").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/section/article/div[1]/div").click()

#This line is being a problem.
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/section/article/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/p/span").send_keys('Heading1')
```

It throws exception like below.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ElementNotInteractableException           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-e483e0f23c79> in <module>
     25 driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/article/div/header/button").click()
     26 driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/section/article/div[1]/div").click()
---> 27 driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/section/article/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/p/span").send_keys('Heading1')
     28 #driver.execute_script("document.getElementByXpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/section/article/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/p/span').value='Heading1'")

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in send_keys(self, *value)
    477         self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
    478                       {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
--> 479                        'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
    480 
    481     # RenderedWebElement Items

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in _execute(self, command, params)
    631             params = {}
    632         params['id'] = self._id
--> 633         return self._parent.execute(command, params)
    634 
    635     def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

I do know what "ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable" means.
Although I tried all the possible Xpath to find an element that I can use `send_keys()`, I failed; It followed by the same exception.

So I looked into the source code of the web editor. It works in a not familiar way by using iframes and lots of elements with auto-generated ids. This is how the editor looks like.

[image]

Here is a short video may give you a bit more idea how the editor works.

https://youtu.be/os2ruSV4jBU

If you have any idea what should I try, please let me know.

*edit

As you can see in the python code, I am considering javascript for web automation. However, the problem is the `span` element which I suspect to work as `input` element, has auto-generated random ID. The only possibility was to select it is using a Xpath, but unfortunately, Javascript don't have `getElementByXpath()`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT 1 - Javascript method

You can try to send text to the `span` element with JavaScript.

Here is a sample:

```
driver.executeScript("document.getElementById('elementID').setAttribute('value', 'yourTextHere')");
```

You can replace ‘elementId’ with the ID of the span element.

EDIT 2 - Javascript method with XPath

I realize your `span` contains dynamic ID and cannot be located by any other method than XPath. For this solution, we can get the `span` using it's XPath, then get it's ID to pass into the Javascript method.

```
IWebElement textAreaElement = driver.findElement(By.XPath("//article//span"));
string textAreaElementId = textAreaElement.GetAttribute("id");
driver.executeScript("document.getElementById('" + textAreaElementId + "').setAttribute('value', 'yourTextHere')");
```

In this sample, you are finding the `span` element using XPath, then you are getting its ID attribute. You pass the ID attribute into the JS function to correctly locate your span element.

Alternatively, you may be able to try just this:

```
IWebElement textAreaElement = driver.findElement(By.XPath("//article//span"));
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'yourTextHere')", textAreaElement);
```

In this case, you are passing the element itself directly into the JS function.

ADDITIONAL EDIT

I noticed you are using absolute XPaths for some of your locators. If you would like to simplify them at all, you can use relative XPath notation like I used above: `//`. I will give you a few examples of some of your XPaths that can be simplified:

Absolute XPath #1

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/article/div/header/button").click()
```

Relative XPath #1

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//article/div/header/button").click()
```

Absolute XPath #2

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/section/article/div[1]/div").click()
```

Relative XPath #2

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//article/div[1]/div").click()
```

You do not need to start all the way at the top of the document's `html` node to use XPath. You can use `//` notation to start your XPath from anywhere on the page.

Comment: If the span is definitely the correct element, you could try sending the text with JavaScript. I will edit my answer with that solution for you.

Comment: Christine, I just edited my question with another screenshot. I considered that method, but it is hard to specify the element.

Comment: @ChanwooAhn Thank you for providing the extra screenshot, this is helpful to me. I have updated my answer with a Javascript solution that can fetch the `span` by XPath and use its ID to call Javascript. I have also added a few XPath tips for you at the bottom. I hope this helps.